How do I reference a step's "with:" property in workflow YAML?
I'm using dorny/paths-filter to detect changes. The problem is I want to run a success job for each of the unchanged filters. This way I can enforce waiting for all jobs in GitHub's rules.
My workflow looks like this:
jobs:
  # JOB to run change detection
  changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Required permissions
    permissions:
      pull-requests: read
    outputs:
      # Expose matched filters as job 'packages' output variable
      changed-packages: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.changes }}
      UNCHANGED-packages: ${{ steps.filter.with.doesnt.exist.  }}
    steps:
    - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v3
      id: filter
      with:
        filters: |
          package1: src/package1
          package2: src/package2

  # JOB to build and test each of modified packages
  build:
    needs: changes
    strategy:
      matrix:
        # Parse JSON array containing names of all filters matching any of changed files
        # e.g. ['package1', 'package2'] if both package folders contains changes
        package: ${{ fromJSON(needs.changes.outputs.changed-packages) }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - ...
    
  # JOB to approve folders that have NOT changed
  approve:
    needs: changes
    strategy:
      matrix:
        # Parse JSON array containing names of all filters matching any of UNCHANGED files
        package: ${{ fromJSON(needs.changes.outputs.UNCHANGED-packages) }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: success()‍♂️‍♂️


I was thinking maybe I can use some combination of setOutput, toJson(), getInput(), maybe jq?
Can I somehow get the object keys for the "with" property? Unfortunately, when I log the toJson(steps) I get:
  {
    "filter": {
      "outputs": {
        "package1": "false",
        "package1_count": "0",
        "package2": "true",
        "package2_count": "3",
        "changes": "[\"package2\"]"
      },
      "outcome": "success",
      "conclusion": "success"
    }
  }

So I don't know what to do. Is there a better library than dorny/paths-filter to accomplish?

Why do you need the inputs to also be outputs? It's just a string, you could e.g. make it an explicit output from another step in the job (filters: {{ steps.define.outputs.filters }}) or even an env var available to all jobs (filters: {{ env.filters }}).

@jonrsharpe you can't use a sequence for env vars. they have to be strings. I have a long list. Not only would it be annoying to have 2 sources of truth, but one of them would have to be a string in manually-typed JSON array (i.e. filters: '["foo", "bar", "etc..."]' instead of nice yaml.

"[env vars] have to be strings" - and the value of with.filters is already a string (see e.g. https://yaml-multiline.info/), so I don't know why that would be an issue.

Because you do not have access to the with.filters from within any step. If you look at the source code for dorny/paths-filter you will see that the package does not actually output the filters input. Consequently you cannot access it from anywhere. (https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter/blob/master/src/main.ts#L247-L259)

But you would if, as I suggested in my first comment, that (string) value was e.g. the output of another previous step, or an env var. Then the filter step and any other step/job that needed it could access it. It's like asking how you get the value of an input you're passing to a function - you're passing it to the function, you already have it.

@jonrsharpe I tried that. but using multi-line syntax to create a list for env vars results in "A sequence was not expected". So I would be forced to make a single-line JSON array string. which is annoying, and not legible.

I don't know what else you tried because you didn't bother including that in your question, but the only value you're showing is "package1: src/package1\npackage2: src/package2", a string, which can be an env var as easily as a with input. But given that you've found your own solution further input seems unnecessary.

I had to use jq and a GitHub run but:
jobs:
  # JOB to run change detection
  changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Required permissions
    permissions:
      pull-requests: read
    outputs:
      # Expose matched filters as job 'packages' output variable
      changed-packages: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.changes }}
      UNCHANGED-packages: ${{ steps.get-unchanged.outputs.unchanged }}
    steps:
    - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v3
      id: filter
      with:
        filters: |
          package1: src/package1
          package2: src/package2
    #   This is where the magic happens 
    - id: unchanged
      run: |
        set -eux
        UNCHANGED=$(echo '${{ toJson(steps.filter.outputs) }}' | jq -c '. | to_entries | map(select(.value | contains("false")) | .key)')
        ALL=$(echo '${{ toJson(steps.filter.outputs) }}' | jq -c '. | to_entries | map(select(.value | contains("false") or contains("true")) | .key)')
        echo "unchanged=$UNCHANGED" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
        echo "all=$ALL" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"


  # JOB to build and test each of modified packages
  changed-packages:
    needs: changes
    strategy:
      matrix:
        # Parse JSON array containing names of all filters matching any of changed files
        # e.g. ['package1', 'package2'] if both package folders contains changes
        package: ${{ fromJSON(needs.changes.outputs.changed-packages) }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - ...
    
  # JOB to approve folders that have NOT changed
  UNCHANGED-packages:
    needs: changes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: true
      matrix:
        project: ${{ fromJSON(needs.changes.outputs.UNCHANGED-packages) }}
    steps:
    - run: echo "No changes for ${{matrix.project}}"


